# Detect named entities inside words using spaCy

Tags: natural-language-processing, chat-bots

I am using rasa nlu for training an NLU system to detect intents and slots. Now, some languages have word endings with their nouns (like Finnish, e.g. "in Berlin" -> "Berliinissä"). I have tried to annotate the characters in the training data as entities, but then I run the model, it doesn't detect the characters inside the word. When those characters are a separate word, only then they're detected. I am unable to think of an implementation to effectively detect named entities within a word. Suggestions needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a tool to decompose composite word. There are many open source softwares for various languages. For example : [german-word-splitter](https://github.com/hiroshi-manabe/german-word-splitter)